# Помогите найти ошибку в алгоритме. Он пропускает число 4 как простое

Tags: c++, алгоритм

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using  namespace std;

bool is_prime(unsigned int num){ 
int limit = num;
int sqr_lim;
vector<bool> is_prime_f(num + 10);
int x2, y2;
int i, j;
int n;

// Инициализация решета
sqr_lim = (int)sqrt((long double)limit);
for (i = 0; i <= limit; i++) is_prime_f[i] = false;
is_prime_f[2] = true;
is_prime_f[3] = true;

// Предположительно простые - это целые с нечетным числом
// представлений в данных квадратных формах.
// x2 и y2 - это квадраты i и j (оптимизация).
x2 = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= sqr_lim; i++) {
    x2 += 2 * i - 1;
    y2 = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= sqr_lim; j++) {
        y2 += 2 * j - 1;

        n = 4 * x2 + y2;
        if ((n <= limit) && (n % 12 == 1 || n % 12 == 5))
            is_prime_f[n] = !is_prime_f[n];

        // n = 3 * x2 + y2; 
        n -= x2; // Оптимизация
        if ((n <= limit) && (n % 12 == 7))
            is_prime_f[n] = !is_prime_f[n];

        // n = 3 * x2 - y2;
        n -= 2 * y2; // Оптимизация
        if ((i > j) && (n <= limit) && (n % 12 == 11))
            is_prime_f[n] = !is_prime_f[n];
    }
}

// Отсеиваем кратные квадратам простых чисел в интервале [5, sqrt(limit)].
// (основной этап не может их отсеять)
for (i = 5; i <= sqr_lim; i++) {
    if (is_prime_f[i]) {
        n = i * i;
        for (j = n; j <= limit; j += n) {
            is_prime_f[j] = false;
        }
    }
}

// Вывод списка простых чисел в консоль.
//printf("2, 3, 5");

if ((i == 2) || (i == 3) || (i == 5))
    return true;

for (i = 6; i <= limit; i++) {  // добавлена проверка делимости на 3 и 5. В оригинальной версии алгоритма потребности в ней нет.
    if ((is_prime_f[i]) && (i % 3 != 0) && (i % 5 !=  0)){
       //printf(", %d", i);
             if (i == num)
                 return true;
    }
}

    return 0; 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (is_prime(983)){
        cout << "prime" << endl;
    }   else {
        cout << "not prime" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Але ж ви знаєте росiйську - виходячи з коментарiв... То чому б вам не використати її ще й для свого запитання? :) Чи це чужий код, який ви хочете видати за свiй? :)

Comment: Я не казав, що цей код мій, просто не люблю винаходити колесо і вирішив скористатись вже готовим рішенням.

Comment: Пишите по-русски, в чем проблема, это SO на русском, а не на украинском.

Comment: Тим більше, що тільки вчуся.

Comment: Там весь код из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно?" - проще с нуля написать правильно, чем копаться...

Comment: Якщо не можете допомогти -- так і скажіть!

Comment: Я тільки почав вчити С++, я не знаю як взагалі зробити цю задачу.

Comment: Через це я й прошу допомогти, алгоритм пропускає перевірку.

Comment: Поищите среди моих ответов другим - я много раз рассказывал, как проверять числа на простоту. Я не хочу впустую тратить время на лентяя, который 1. не удосужился прочесть правила сайта, несмотря на недвусмысленные намеки, 2. пытается не разбираясь сдать чужой код, 3. даже не пытался выполнить поиск на сайте...  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE

Comment: Дякую за відвертість! Я вже шукав альтернативний код, але ні один не працював. Але, якби там не було, все-одно дякую.

Comment: Я уже бросил вам ссылку... Ну ее-то хоть посмотрите!

Comment: Дякую! У мене просто моб. інтернет :(

Comment: А программы запускаете тоже на мобильном?

Comment: Ні, я працюю на ноуті,  просто роздачу на смарті включив.